# C# changing selection between 2 listboxes

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitem, listboxitems, listbox-control

So the following code has the obvious error that when the user changes the selection between the two listboxes they are both cleared. What is the best way to select an item in listbox2 whilst simultaneously unselecting the item in listbox1 visa versa.

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
     listbox2.ClearSelected()
    }

    private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
     listbox1.ClearSelected()
    }
```

I would love to claim just asking for a friend but I can't seem to figure this simple one out...

For clarification the code does work when I select an item from listbox1, listbox2 is then unselected. The problem is that listbox2 is changed immediately unselecting the item from listbox1 that was just clicked

Comment: *Unselected* means *selected index = `-1`*. Why do you want to clear selection in first place (give us real scenario, maybe your approach is wrong by itself)? You can utilize focus events to prevent `SelectedIndexChanged` event processing for *active* `ListBox`.

Comment: The code should work, unless you didn't show us other events changing the selection or the focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify both functions as follows:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  if (bChanging) return;
  bChanging = true;
  listbox2.ClearSelected();
  bChanging = false;
}
```

`bChanging` is a member of the form.
This or a similar construct should work.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfect. I knew it would be simple